# Azure Data Factory Copying a cell value incorrectly when copying data from Azure Blob Storage To Azure SQLDB

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse

I am in the process of building a grocery list app with Azure.

Currently, I have an azure function that writes json files to blob storage. Here is what my current blob storage looks like:
[image: picture of my data in blob storage from ADF]
When Azure data factory copies over the data to my SQL DB, this is what it looks like:
[image: picture of my grocery list table]
Here is the code that I am using to create my table:

```
-- Create a new table called 'groceryitems' in schema 'grocerylistapp'
-- Drop the table if it already exists
IF OBJECT_ID('grocerylistapp.groceryitems', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE grocerylistapp.groceryitems
GO

CREATE SCHEMA grocerylistapp
GO

-- Create the table in the specified schema
CREATE TABLE grocerylistapp.groceryitems
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1), -- Primary Key column
    epoch DATE,
    [name] VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([id] ASC)
    -- Specify more columns here
);
GO
1
```

Oddly enough, when I originally did this with Data Warehouse / Synapse, I didn't get this issue, so I am assuming it is something to do particularly with SQL DB.

I also want to add that it randomly decides to distort one row, if I had 3,4, or 5 items in blob storage, it would pick one row and distort it as shown in the screenshot. It is not always the same item.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you have chosen the `json` format file as Soure dataset.

Here're the steps I tested,  and it works well.

**Source dataset(json format) from Blob storage:**

[image]

Import the cchema of the source dataset:
[image]

Sink dataset settings:

[image]

Mapping settings:

[image]

Run the pipeline:

[image]

Check the data in table `grocerylistapp.groceryitems`:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Leon. I figured it out, it was that I was missing the **"Mapping"** portion. By default it was inserting the ID, which is not what you are supposed to do for auto incrementing primary keys. **By mapping only the name and epoch, sql db works as expected.**